# Intellij - only one tab in main window

Tags: class, intellij-idea

i have problem with Intellij Idea (EAP Ultimate). Something happens with setting and i can open only one tab in main window, when I open the second tab the first one closes. I can find any trigger to this functions i settings. Please, help me.

Comment: Please check that tabs limit isn't set to "1" in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Editor Tabs"

Comment: I have this same issue. I can only open one file at a time. When I open a new file, it just replaces the previous file in the tab. The only way to get multiple tabs is to pin them.

Comment: please hit SHIFT twice, go to 'Actions', find 'Open files in preview tab' - that should be OFF. if it does not help please try to reset IDE settings: File -> Manage IDE settings -> Restore default settings.

Comment: another one option in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Advanced Settings | Open declaration source in the same tab option is enabled and could be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-255328

The option "Advanced Settings -> Open declaration source in the same tab" is broken so that files are always opened in the same tab, not just when you navigate to a declaration.

The bug is marked as fixed, but I still see it in IntelliJ 2021.2.1, so I would assume that the fix will come in 2021.3.

As a workaround, disable "Advanced Settings -> Open declaration source in the same tab".

Answer (score 1):

[Yuri Win](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67637909/intellij-only-one-tab-in-main-window#comment121753073_67637909) comment did the trick for me.

Since it is on a comment and not as an answer I reproduce it here.

> Please hit SHIFT twice, go to 'Actions', find 'Open files in preview
> tab' - that should be OFF.

---

Other way of doing so is to open *IntelliJ* Settings, and in *Editor -> Editor Tabs*, section *Opening Policy* uncheck the *Enable preview tab*.

[image]